# AWS S3 bucket size reduced after configuring life cycle with Transisition to Standard IA class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Few days back I tried to configure a life cycle for S3 bucket intending to move old files to Glacier. 
I configured a LifeCycle for that bucket and added transistion to Standard IA class after 31 days of object creation.

After 1 day, the bucket size came down from 3.7TB to 80GB data. Where can we see and access those files .. ? Are the files got deleted . ? Or moved to glacier or Standard IA class .. ? How can we see and retrieve those lost files .. ?

Please help me in understanding the issue and how to get back those lost files.. ?

Comment: How are you measuring the size of the bucket? If your files were transitioned to either standard_ia or glacier, they are still "in" the bucket and can still be seen in the S3 console.

Answer (score -1):

Amazon Glacier provides a management console, which you can use to create and delete vaults. However, you cannot download archives from Amazon Glacier by using the management console. To download data, such as photos, videos, and other documents, you must either use the AWS CLI or write code to make requests, by using either the REST API directly or by using the AWS SDKs.

Check this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/downloading-an-archive.html) for more info.

Comment: This is technically correct, but seems entirely unrelated to the question, which is about S3 lifecycle policies.